# How to print all prime numbers in c++?

Tags: c++, primes

I'm trying to print all the prime numbers in series, the code I ended up with is below, instead of printing all primes it prints random numbers, Some are prime and some are not :/
Why is that so?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

long int x,y=3;
int a=3;
bool isprime;

int main()
{
    while(a<=100)
    {
    for(x=2;x<=y;x++)
    {
        if(y%x==0 && x!=y)
        {
            isprime=false;
            break;
        }
        else if(y%x!=0 && x!=y)
        {
            isprime = true;
        }

    }
    if(isprime==true  && y%x!=0 && x!=y)
    {
        cout<<a<<" is a prime number."<<"\n";
        isprime=false;
    }

      a++;
      y++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should only paste codes that's relevant to the problem. There are too many variables never been used in the code now.

Comment: Besides, the variable `y` was initialized to `3` and never been changed since then. What's it for?

Comment: y is the number, and is to limit the primes to 100... I'll revise the code.. EDIT: Thanks that fixed it, I used a in place of why in one place and forgot to increment y.. Thanks! :D

Comment: "all prime numbers" is a pretty huge amount of numbers to print...

Comment: I know, actually I was attempting project euler 7th problem, So I wanted the 10001st prime and I got it..  :D

Answer (score 1):

This

```
if(isprime=true && a%x!=0 && a!=y)
```

should be this

```
if(isprime==true && a%x!=0 && a!=y)
```

That's a common mistake. But even better is to realise that you don't need to compare bools against true of false, because they *are* true or false. So just

```
if (isprime && a%x!=0 && a!=y)
```

The logic just looks all wrong (and way too complicated), try this

```
    isprime = true;
    for(x=2;x<a;x++)
    {
        if(a%x==0)
        {
            isprime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isprime)
    {
        cout<<a<<"\n";
    }
```

No need for y.

Comment: Thanks will try it and let you know :)

Comment: That didn't work, I still get some non-primes in the output, like 55,65 and 85. Why is that so?

Comment: @Rohanchrome No guarantees that fixes all the problems, I haven't examined the logic of your code. I'll have another look.

Comment: Thanks, The logic was correct, Although the implementation was wrong. I've improved it and edited the post, It all works now! Thanks! :D

Comment: You should use good names for your variables.  `x` and `a` could be `candidate` and `divisor`.  This isn't code golf. Also, instead of testing to `x/2`, you need only test until the square root of `x`. Try performing the Sieve of Erastothenes by hand for the numbers up to 100 to see that viscerally. You'll notice that you get no further primes once you pass 7, the largest prime less than the root of 100.  Finally, put the prime testing into a separate function.

Answer (score 1):

Well what jumps into my eyes is that you never increment y.

y is 3 in the beginning, so you only try if 2 is a possible divisor of a and then go to the next a.

Anyway, I am not sure what you wanted to achieve with y.

Let x run from 2 to a/2, as there is no need to try numbers bigger than a/2.
This is simply because there never will be a divisor bigger than a/2.
Example: a = 30. It would not make sense to try to divide by 16 or bigger, as the result can never be a integer (besides a itself of course)

However, this should do what you want:

```
int x = 0; 
int a = 0;
bool isPrime = false;

for(a=3; a < 100; a+=2) 
{
    isPrime = true;
    for(x = 2; x <= a/2; x++) {
        if(a%x == 0) {
            isPrime = false;
            break;                                     
        }                    
    }
    if(isPrime) {
        cout << a << "\n";            
    }
}
```

there are of course other algorithms that can find primes, but I wanted to use your approach basically.

Cheers

Chris

EDIT:
Someone was faster :)

anyway: there is no need to run higher than a/2, this is a important optimization...!

EDIT2:

another optimization is of course skipping all even numbers, so start with a = 3 and increment by 2 for each loop iteration...

Answer (score 1):

I see your code is ok now. 
Nevertheless I made small changes, cleaning the code and making it a little bit faster.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

long int x, y = 2;
int a = 3;
bool isprime;

int main() {
    while (a <= 100) {
        while ((y + 1) * (y + 1) <= a) {
            y++;
        }

        isprime = true;
        for (x = 3; x <= y; x += 2) {
            if (a % x == 0) {
                isprime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isprime) {
            cout << a << " is a prime number." << "\n";
        }

        a+=2;
    }
}
```